# Testing GoLang Invoke method that makes a call to another chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have been trying to test my chaincodes using the shims "MockStub" to carry out testing on my chaincode and have come across an issue.

```
  Root
  |
  Some folder
  |
  chaincode 
  ├── chaincode1
  │   ├── chaincode1.go
  │   ├── chaincode1_test.go
  │  
  └── chaincode2
      ├── chaincode2.go
      ├── chaincode2_test.go
  |
  Other folders
```

Suppose the above heirarchy when I run a MockInvoke in chaincode1 and have some of its values passed on to another function to carry out some tasks. The problem is this chaincode uses the shims `InvokeChaincode` function and calls another chaincode (like `chaincode2`). Is there anyway I can pass a `MockPeerChaincode` along with the MockInvoke to solve this issue or this any other way?

```
Chaincode-1
func Insert(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) pb.Response{
//Add to blockchain but create an account
....
makeAccount(stub,AccountIDhash,AccountBalance)
....
}
func makeAccount(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, accountID string, amount string){
 .....
//function includes converting the accountID and ammount to chaincode arguments
//this method invokes the secondchaincode(chaincode2)
response := stub.InvokeChaincode("chaincode2", chaincodearguments, "mychannel")
if response.Status != shim.OK {
    return shim.Error("chaincode1: " + "Unable to create new account from chaincode")
}
return shim.Success([]byte("chaincode1: " + "created new account from chaincode"))


}
....other methods in Chaincode1
```

Comment: Please include your code.

Answer (score 1):

Define you code is such a way that it operates on interfaces, so that you can use mock struct that implements your interface definitions. 
If all the dependencies are based on interface they can be easily be mocked.